# How to get a random number every time a function is called in C

Tags: c, random

So I'm making a game that needs to generate a random number every time the attack function is called. For every run of the program it generates a a different one, I think this is because I use srand(time(NULL)); however, if I attack more than once, the it returns the same number that I already called. Here is a sample of my random function at the moment.

```
srand(time(NULL));
int attrand = rand() % 16;
```

How can I make it return a different number every time it is called within the same execution of the program?

Answer (score 8):

Move the seed initialization to some init function, and keep only `int attrand = rand() % 16;` in this function.

```
void my_init() {
    srand(time(NULL));
}

int get_random() {
    return rand() % 16;
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks! So when do i call my_init? Every time before I use get_random?

Comment: No, that'll miss the whole point, you should call it only one (let's say from main, or whatever fits you)